# LibreOffice: Autocomplete dates with month and year, no day

Tags: libreoffice-calc, date

I'm using `Libreoffice 4.4` and I want to drag down a column in format `Month Year`. For example: `May 2015`. I do not need days.

I tried to drag down after doing this schema for 3 cells but it doesn't work: it is incrementing the days and not the months. Changing the format to show only days didn't help.

Can someone tell me how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

1. select the entire column;
2. select menu `Format` -> `Cells` or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
3. On the `numbers` tab, select `Date` category;
4. Select `English (USA)` as language;
5. Set `MMMM YYYY` as user-defined format pattern:

   [image]
6. That's it - hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Now, if you enter "Jan 2015" or "January 2015", LO Calc will expand it to "January 2015" and handle it internally as "01/01/2015". If you enter "Feb 2015" in the next cell and drag both cells down, Calc will increment the month:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ahhh I did exactly the same. My issue was that I just dragged down one cell and not two; if you drag down two cells it does work! Thank you @tohuwawohu